# Changed servers now certain parts of cakePHP site not working

Tags: php, cakephp

i moved from godaddy to host1plus, both vps

the site works perfectly fine, except for the spell check function and the preview function

when I mean functions, the site uses some plugins i believe

I see this in the code:

```
spellcheck/extensions/modalbox/modalbox.combined.js
```

The site basically creates resumes, and there is a spell check of the resume, and then there is a preview of the resume, both of these functions don't work now.

The spell check comes up, but nothing happens.

The other part that's not working is the final preview of the resume.

The old server was php version 5.4 new server is 5.6.30 would that be an issue?

Comment: have you checked your browser's console for any errors?

Comment: No I did not (i'm a novice), i'll look into that good suggestion

Comment: I believe that it is some javascript error rather than a php problem

Comment: javascript is browser run and not server run isn't that correct? so if just moved to another server, wouldn't javascript still work? Maybe i'm wrong, i know little about this.

Comment: As Manos said you need to use the browser's developer tools to see if the javascript is loaded and runs successfully. Do you know if the JS makes any ajax calls back to your server-side code? right click the page and click inspect element. the developer tools will show up, now check console tab and network tab for any errors. TIP: you may need to refresh the page to see output in those tabs

Comment: Ok cheers, i'll look into this now.

Comment: Javascript is on the client side.Maybe when you moved your site you forgot to move some js files.Anyway check your dev console it is the only way to know if it is a javascript error or not